# How to download multiple files using ExpressJS one API call

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, download

I'm quite new to expressjs and I'm developing a web application which acts as an API application. There is a react frontend application also. When a button is clicked in the client app it will send an API call to the backend app and will download a file. That scenario is working fine.with the following code.

```
  const file = `${__dirname}/upload-folder/dramaticpenguin.MOV`;
  res.download(file); // Set disposition and send it.
});
```

But now I have a requirement to download multiple files from a button click. How can I do that .
Can someone help me here.

Answer (score 2):

An HTTP response can only have one file. Really, "downloading a file" in HTTP means serving a response with a [`Content-Disposition: attachment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header, to hint to the client that this response should be saved to the filesystem instead of rendered in the browser.

To download multiple files, you want the *client* code to initiate multiple HTTP requests (probably to different URLs), and the server can respond to each request with a different file. Note that many browsers will refuse to download multiple files in response to a single user action (for fear of flooding the user with unwanted files) or will at least prompt for confirmation before doing so.

If you cannot change your client-side code to make multiple requests, you will need to package your files inside a single file archive.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, any idea on how to do the zipping and downloading the file.